# Does mobiscroll have a method to get the day of week?

Tags: mobiscroll

Does mobiscroll have a method to get the day of week in given language (set from 'lang' option). I could not find in the [docs](https://docs.mobiscroll.com/jquery/calendar#methods).

Bellow is a snippet code what I want to achieve.

```
$('#mobiscroll').mobiscroll().calendar({
    onSet: function (event, inst) {
      var DayOfWeek = event. // ex: Saturday
      var Day = event. // ex: 20
      var Year = event. // ex: 2020
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get it from the [dayNames array](https://docs.mobiscroll.com/jquery/calendar#localization-dayNames), but I'm not sure how does that help you?